# Записываются данные только из одного инпута React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

После ввода данных в инпут , в стейт записывается значение "compiled" так же для title , т.е если вводить false то и в title оказывается false , хотя там вводилось другое значение, в чем ошибка?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './AddForm.css'
import axios from 'axios';



class AddForm extends Component{
    state = {

        title: '',
        completed: ''
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ title: event.target.value, completed: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();


        const API = ''
        axios.put(API, {data: {title: this.state.title, completed: this.state.completed}})
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        title:
                        <input type="text" name="title" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        completed:
                        <input type="text" name="completed" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </label>

                    <button type="submit">Add user</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default AddForm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что по твоему эта строка делает `this.setState({ title: event.target.value, completed: event.target.value});`? В независимости от того, в какой инпут ты вводишь данные, этот код перезаписывает сразу два поля твоего состояния тем, что ты вводишь в данный момент.

В твоём случае можно сделать во так:

```
class AddForm extends Component {

  state = {
    title: "",
    completed: ""
  };

  handleChange = event => {
     if (event.target.name === "title")
       this.setState({ title: event.target.value });
     if (event.target.name === "completed")
       this.setState({ completed: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            title:
            <input type="text" name="title" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>

          <label>
            completed:
            <input type="text" name="completed" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>

          <button type="submit">Add user</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

или для разных инпутов сделать две разные функции.